# How to convert in ffmpeg at a constant bitrate?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, video-encoding

I recently began encoding some of my videos, but can't seem to make `ffmpeg` encode at a constant bitrate as all my videos turn out to have variable bitrates. I have tried multiple commands, but nothing produces an output with a clean, stable bitrate. This has been my to-go command so far:

`ffmpeg -i "input.file" -c:v libx265 -crf 17 -preset veryslow -b:v 10000k -minrate 10000k -maxrate 10000k "output.file"`

The latest conversion ended up at 4.5 Mbps straight from a source file.

How to encode while keeping the bitrate constant?

Comment: try removing `-crf 17` since `-crf` is used when you *don't care about the exact bitrate* - you probably won't want `-preset` either

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks man, I'll try it out when doing my next encoding!

Comment: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f mpegts -muxrate 4000K -y out.mp4` according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596633/7986904).